# GFCI Breaker for Kitchen

Tags: gfci, nec

In the brand new Houses, I have noticed that the builders are using the gfci breaker instead of the outlet. I understand that it's more comprehensive coverage and satisfies the NEC code requirements. But my questions are:

Should gfci be used for large appliances like refrigerator and freezer? Or, in general, is it a good idea to use gfci for the entire kitchen instead of using the outlets?

Also, is that true that GFCI breakers can make a trip condition ambiguous and more difficult to find out why the breaker trips, was it on a ground fault or an overcurrent/short?

And the last question is how often a gfci breaker needs to be tested? I know that the outlets are every month.

Comment: Think the recommendation is for fridges/freezers to be on their own(dedicated) circuit/outlet without GFCI protection.  The rest of kitchen outlets must have GFCI protection.  Some GFCI breakers have light/s that will flash with error code.

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Testing would be the same (if you are the unusual person who actually does that beyond a month or two when they are new.)

Many GFCI, AFCI and GFCI/AFCI combination breakers have fault code indicators that provide information about the cause of a trip. Some are better at it than others, many end users don't bother to learn about it at all, so it does not help them until they do learn, if they ever do. In general you don't get much choice in GFCI breakers, since they need to be ones specifically listed for use in your breaker panel.

Many people (myself included) prefer to have refrigerators and freezers on a dedicated (not shared with countertop outlets) non-GFCI outlet. If the outlet is not usable as a countertop outlet and is not within 6 feet of a sink, that generally meets code. Some places do, and others do not, have an exception specifically for refrigeration appliances (so, for instance, a freezer in a garage where all outlets are supposed to be GFCI protected can be on a dedicated freezer outlet that is not GFCI protected, in those jurisdictions. That is a local modification to the broader NEC requirement, and may not apply to your local jurisdiction.)

The benefit of having GFCI protection at the breaker, rather than the first outlet, is small, since the wiring between those two points is only going to have a ground fault under some very odd and unusual circumstances. An AFCI provides a more obvious benefit as a breaker rather than first device (but if installed per code **in metallic conduit to the first device**, arguably similar benefits. But lots of people don't like to run conduit.)

Comment: Is it really a question of what you prefer? The electrical code in most jurisdictions specifies that countertop receptacle circuits (the ones that are most likely to be near the sink and therefore require GFCI protection) must not be shared with fixed appliances. In other words, you’re not allowed to have a countertop receptacle and a refrigerator on the same circuit. And many codes specify that the refrigerator MUST be on its own dedicated circuit.

Comment: Both NEC code changes over time and "Local modifications that are not in the NEC" come into play here, as well as things that are not actually in the NEC that become myth. "In the kitchen, pantry, breakfast room, dining room, or similar area of a dwelling unit, the two or more 20-ampere small-appliance branch circuits required by 210.11(C)(1) shall serve all wall and floor receptacle outlets covered by 210.52(A), all countertop outlets covered by 210.52(C), and receptacle outlets for refrigeration equipment." So the NEC specifically puts them on the same circuit...

Comment: However: "Exception No. 2: In addition to the required receptacles specified by 210.52, a receptacle outlet to serve a specific appliance shall be permitted to be supplied from an individual branch circuit rated 15 amperes or greater." Permitted - not required. Above, too late to edit: Technically, it puts them on the same group of circuits, since there can be more than the minimum 2 required.

Comment: CEC is not the same…

Answer (score 4):

> Should gfci be used for large appliances like refrigerator and freezer?

Not if you can avoid it.  The purpose of GFCI protection is to protect humans from electric shock.  A refrigerator is grounded, heavy, all the electrics are in the very bottom back (impossible to get an arm near in most installations), and you're not likely to drop it in your sink.  It's just not the use-case for GFCI.

> Or, in general, is it a good idea to use gfci for the entire kitchen instead of using the outlets?

Well, a kitchen is *required* to have between 4 and 8 circuits depending on what your appliances are, so there's no such thing as putting the GFCI "on the kitchen circuit, singular".

A clever person might think "how about a 60A hot tub GFCI and then power a subpanel in the kitchen that feeds all those circuits?" Well, it's normal to have tiny amounts of ordinary leakage to ground (e.g. just from capacitance). The European experience is that when you put that much stuff on one GFCI, that ordinary leakage exceeds 5 milliamps, and you get a lot of "nuisance trips".  So they have to "de-tune" their whole-house RCD (GFCI by another name) to 30 milliamp sensitivity, which degrades degrades its usefulness for human protection somewhat.  This would fail to meet NEC standards.

> Also, is that true that GFCI breakers can make a trip condition ambiguous and more difficult to find out why the breaker trips, was it on a ground fault or an overcurrent/short?

That *really* depends on the breaker.  The newer breakers have diagnostic readouts which tell you the reason for the trip.  The quality of these varies dramatically.

Eaton's new breakers are the best, with 7 different fault codes, even distinguishing *type* of arc fault, and overcurrent vs short!  I wish they'd roll out that generation into the Eaton CL and CHQ lines, which are approved for competitor panels.  (bus stabs on each panel have a slightly different shape, and they don't make good contact. I believe Eaton CL does a trick with soft metals to solve that.)